# What is the domain and range of the function $f(x)= \frac{1}{\tan{x}}$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The function:

$f(x)= \frac{1}{\tan{x}}$

We've written in class that the domain of this function is $ \{x|x \ne n\pi\} $ where $n$ is an integer, and that the range is equal to $R - \{0\}$

Now what I dont underatand is that if the range doesn't include $0$ , shouldn't the domain exclude $ x=\frac{\pi}{2}+ n\pi $, where n is an integer as well?

Comment: The user is talking about $n\pi + \frac{\pi}2$

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It's fixed now

Comment: I know, but isn't that related to the function's limit at that point rather than its value? Sure the limit exists, but the function is undefined at that point

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're right: $\tan x$ has to be defined for $1/\tan x$ to be defined. However, you may rewrite it as $\cos x/\sin x$, and this one is perfectly defined if $x\equiv \frac\pi 2\mod\pi$.

Comment: But the problem is we didn't do that for other functions where the limit existed at a certain point, but the function was undefined at it. So it's kind of weird to make this an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The only way you could include $\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$ in the domain would be if you are allowing "$\infty$" as a value, and calculating $\dfrac{1}{\infty}=0$, in which case to be consistent, $0$ would also have to be in the range.  Making that choice is done more commonly when working with [meromorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) in complex analysis.  But in terms of functions with real number inputs and outputs, if $\tan(x)$ isn't defined, then neither is $\dfrac{1}{\tan(x)}$.  And if $a$ is a real number, then $\dfrac{1}{a}\neq 0$, which is the reason $0$ is not in the range in that context.  So the statement of the domain is missing just what you said.

---

Added: However, the points of the form $\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi$ are "removable singularities", and this function is "essentially" equal to $\cot(x)$.  If it were simply $\cot(x)$, then it would have the domain you stated, and the range would include $0$.  In some cases removing removable singularities is a good default position to take, but different instructors may disagree.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I'll be sure to ask my teacher as well to see what he meant

Comment: Also , how should I write that domain ? I'm not sure to be honest

Comment: "All real numbers except integer multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$", a.k.a. "$\mathbb R\setminus (\mathbb Z\frac{\pi}{2})$", a.k.a. "$\{x\in\mathbb R: \forall n\in\mathbb Z, x\neq n\frac{\pi}{2}\}$" (if you know what that notation means; $\mathbb R$=set of real numbers, $\mathbb Z$ = set of integers, $\forall$ = for all), or any other way that clearly conveys the same meaning to whomever needs to know what you mean.

Comment: Alright, Thanks again!